# Cannot create object of inherit class of MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create object of login which is inherit from MainWindow(Default window created in c# code)
Here is my code :

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       login ins = new login();
       .
       .
       .
       .
    }
  public class login
    {
       public login(){}
    }
```

Its giving error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred

Comment: do you have the stacktrace?

Comment: Does login actually inherit from MainWindow? It doesn't in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By deriving from `MainWindow` you invoke the instructor of `MainWindow` each time you instantiate `login`.

Thus, your code does:

1. Make "MainWindow"
2. "MainWindow" creates login
3. "Login" inherits "MainWindow" so it makes a new one
4. New "MainWindow" makes a new "Login"
5. Reapeat ad infinitum
6. StackOverflow!

Your "Login" class shouldn't derive from "MainWindow" (and neither should anything else!)